# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field Not showing up on front-end

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on my WordPress child theme and utilizing Advanced Custom Fields, but I'm having a pain displaying one of them on the front-end.

```
    <?php if( get_field('pp-full-image') ): ?>

<? // closes main .row and .container from header & inserts full width image ?> 
</div><!-- .row from header -->
</div><!-- .container from header -->

<div class="pp-sub" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('pp-full-image'); ?>)"></div>

<!-- .pp-sub -->

<? // displays section 3 content ?>
<?php $ppsec3 = get_field('pp-section3');
if( $ppsec3 ): ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">


            
                <div class="pp-sec sec3">
                    <h3 class="pp-title sec3"><?php echo ( $ppsec3['pp-section3-title'] ); ?></h3>
                    <div class="pp-txt sec3">
                        <?php echo ( $ppsec3['pp-section3-text'] ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        </div><!-- /.pp-wrapper -->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>     
<? // closes section 3 content ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<? // closes full width image and section 3 content  ?>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Please more specific regarding the problem you're encountering. Which value isn't appearing? Are the other fields you're setting showing up as expected? Are you confident the field that isn't appearing has a value set for it?

Comment: Why the paranthesis around this line? echo ( $ppsec3['pp-section3-text'] );